# How to add today() to one more textbox

Tags: vb.net

```
txtFromDate.Text = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
txtToDate.Text = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I have a code as above and i want to shorten my code as below but i think it's not correct:

```
txtFromDate.Text = txtToDate.Text = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I looking for your guide,
Thanks,

Comment: The better way would be to add an extra line: `Dim initialDate = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` `txtFromDate.Text = initialDate` `txtToDate.Text = initialDate`.

Comment: and if you have many, you could loop over them: `For each lbl As Label in {txtFromDate, txtToDate, txtAnotherone, ...}   lbl.text = initialDate Next`check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) if you're unfamiliar with loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtFromDate.Text = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
txtToDate.Text = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

or

```
txtFromDate.Text = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
txtToDate.Text = txtFromDate.Text
```

or (from: Andrew Morton)

```
Dim DateStr as String = Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
txtFromDate.Text = DateStr 
txtToDate.Text = DateStr
```

or (from: AConfusedSimpleton)

```
For each lbl As Label in {txtFromDate, txtToDate, txtAnotherone, ...}
    lbl.text = initialDate
Next
```

or

```
txtFromDate.Text = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : txtToDate.Text = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Your attempt at shortening will not do what you want it will evaulate the line as boolean logic

```
txtFromDate.Text = txtToDate.Text = Today().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
txtFromDate.Text = FALSE //(or 0, not sure)
```